# Git Authentication Failed when having username and password in the URI

Tags: git, authentication

I'm trying to set a Satis Composer repository. I have this git repository which is hosted on the Microsoft TFS platform and is accessible over HTTPS.

Satis on build is trying to clone the git repository. It is asking me for the username and password, which I provide and it results with an authentication error. I can see that Satis has inserted credentials into the URL, like this: `https://user:pass@git.repo.com/repository`

I did some experimenting and I found that `git clone https://user:pass@git.repo.com/repository` always ends up with authentication failure.

However if I do `git clone https://user@git.repo.com/repository` or `git clone https://git.repo.com/repository` I get a prompt to enter the credentials. This way it always works!

I have stored the credentials with `git credential.helper store` command but it keeps asking for them anyway.

I must be doing something wrong. Could you guys shed some light onto my problem, please?

Comment: Does your password contain any special characters that would need to be URL-encoded?

Comment: Initially it did but I have changed it. Right now there are only letters, numbers and a dot (.). Hmm... is that dot the problem, then?

Comment: Anyway, I have changed my password to contain only alphanum characters and it still doesn't work.

Comment: By using `git config --global credential.helper store` I managed to get satis to work without asking for credentials. Not ideal but works. Still, it doesn't answer my question but raises another: why I had to use global configuration, why local was not enough?